# ASP.NET Core 2.0 ef using GeographyPoint - The entity type 'CoordinateSystem' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

ASP.NET Core 2.0 ef  using `GeographyPoint`  - The entity type 'CoordinateSystem' requires a primary key to be defined

My project has been working fine until I added a new model with `GeographyPoint`.

This exception pops up during `DatabaseEnsureCreate()`.

I'm stuck and can't seem to get past this. Here's a code snippet from my model:

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Spatial;

    //Id
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Description = "Id",Name = "Id", Prompt = "Id")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    public new int Id { get; set; }


    //Geography Point
    [Column(TypeName = DatabaseExtension.TypeNameInteger)]
    [Display(Description = "Geography Point", Name = "Geography Point", 
    Prompt = "Geography Point")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    public GeographyPoint Point { get; set; }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post your whole CoordonateSystem class?

Comment: You can't use `GeographyPoint` as a type, are you able to use `DbGeography` instead?

Comment: The 'CoordinateSystem' message shows when I add  GeographyPoint to a model ..  I do not have a 'CoordinateSystem' class.

Comment: DbGeography does not work. Typing in Geography shows options of changing Geography to GeographyCurve,GeographyPoint and GeographyPolygon

Comment: Read [ask], provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" then? That's the standard way to use spatial/geography data with Entity Framework.

Comment: It would appear that DbGeography is now Geography in EF Core. It appears that the standard way has changed. Hence this is the reason why I need help

Comment: Oh, EF Core.... in that case, spatial types are not yet supported in EF Core, you'll have to look at another option I'm afraid.